# Does chaining a list provide any benefit?

Tags: python, python-itertools

As I dimly understand it, itertools.chain.from_iterable is for combining two or more things that return iterables, i.e. things that use the yield keyword and when used as such they are memory efficient.

I have this code I'm trying to decipher. Someone else wrote it.

```
all_rows = []
with open(__file__, 'rt') as reader:
    for row in reader:
        all_rows.append(row)
magic = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(all_rows))
for line in magic:
    print(line)
```

Wouldn't it be better to just use all_rows directly since it is already an in memory data structure?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not chaining one list. You are chaining the **contents** of that list:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> all_rows = ['lorem ipsum', 'and so on']
>>> list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(all_rows))
['l', 'o', 'r', 'e', 'm', ' ', 'i', 'p', 's', 'u', 'm', 'a', 'n', 'd', ' ', 's', 'o', ' ', 'o', 'n']
```

You'd have a point if your code was simply using `chain(all_rows)` instead of `chain.from_iterable(all_rows)`; then you are absolutely right. There is no point in chaining off a single iterable that is already a list, then convert that chain to a list again.

But the [`itertools.chain.from_iterable()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable) takes the *contents* of an iterable and chains those together. It then depends on the elements in the list.

For your example, chaining multiple strings, the advantage is that you don't have to build a larger list first. You'd otherwise have to use `list(''.join(all_rows))`.

Comment: Shoot, my example must have a bug. Anyhow, the actual code reads in files to a list of strings and then calls list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(all_rows)) before iterating across the rows in a for-in loop.

Comment: @MatthewMartin: that does sound wasteful, why build a list when iterating in a loop? If you don't need random access, then don't call `list()` on that and just iterate.

Comment: @MatthewMartin: also, if the actual code reads in files into a list of strings, consider using a generator that produces those contents instead to not have to hold everything in memory.

Comment: Thanks, this confirms my suspicion. For what it's worth, some other developer wrote this & seems to have wrapped a lot of already-in-memory lists with this from_iterable